# Upgrading to Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE - failed to instantiate hazelcast

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, spring-webflux

I'm upgrading from Spring 4.3.x to 5.0.0.
After fixing some references to hibernate5 related classes, I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'hazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:575)
    ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.hazelcast.hibernate.serialization.Hibernate4CacheEntrySerializerHook.createSerializer(Hibernate4CacheEntrySerializerHook.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.registerSerializerHooks(DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.build(DefaultSerializationServiceBuilder.java:220)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultNodeExtension.createSerializationService(DefaultNodeExtension.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.<init>(Node.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:111)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
```

....

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl.<init>([Ljava.io.Serializable;, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
        at com.hazelcast.hibernate.serialization.Hibernate42CacheEntrySerializer.<clinit>(Hibernate42CacheEntrySerializer.java:47)
```

Anyone encountered the issue? does hazelcast supports spring 5.0.0? I didn't find and documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of certain internal changes in Hibernate you need another version of the integration. See the correct integration here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate5

Comment: Looks like hazelcast-hibernate5 latest version (1.0?) depends on hazelcast-3.7-E.A.
Is there an official version I can use?

Comment: After upgrading to hazelcast-hibernate5, getting this:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl.<init>([Ljava.io.Serializable;, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
        at com.hazelcast.hibernate.serialization.Hibernate51CacheEntrySerializer.<clinit>(Hibernate51CacheEntrySerializer.java:47)

Comment: Please file an issue on github, possible that is not compatible with 5.0 anymore but only 5.1

Comment: Do you mean hibernate 5.1 @noctarius ?

Comment: Fixed after I upgraded to hazelcast-hibernate52 version 1.2.2.